# NSFetchedResultsController - New Syntax?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, core-data, nsfetchedresultscontroller

I started reading up about the NSFetchedResultsController today, but I've come across some confusing syntax, can someone please describe what the following two lines mean? Specifically the `id <something>`

```
id <NSFetchedResultsSectionInfo> sectionInfo = [[fetchedResultsController sections] objectAtIndex:section];
```

and

```
NSManagedObjectContext *context = <#Managed object context#>;
```

Also, please confirm my understanding that the NSFetchedResultsController is simply a kind of NSMutableArray but with additional functionality (delegate messages) specifically for controlling Core Data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`id<PROTO> foo` declares a variable `foo` whose type is "pointer to object conforming to protocol PROTO". This means that it is only okay to send the messages in the `PROTO` protocol to `foo`.

`<#Managed Object Context#>` is not valid Objective-C syntax. It's just saying, "stick the code to get a reference to your MOC here."

`NSFetchedResultsController` is not related to `NSMutableArray`. The only thing they have in common is that both provide access to ordered collections. `NSFetchedResultsController` stands between you and managed object context. Its content is determined by what is in the context and the fetch request supplied when the fetched results controller is created. It mediates access to the MOC and uses cached data whenever possible. Its intended use is as an easy way to get data from Core Data into a `UITableView`.

Comment: It's also worth noting that FRC further differs from NSMutableArray in that it supports multiple sections, with the result that its contents can be accessed using an NSIndexPath via the itemAtIndexPath: method.